# How to read content of a file and then split the content into several files?

Tags: ruby, regex, rubygems

Suppose, I have a file with the following text:

**old_file**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "animals", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "kind"
end
```

I need to split this file so that every **create_table** block would be created on different files. For instance:

**file1**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
end
```

**file2**

```
create_table "animals", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "kind"
end
```

I can read the file and than assign it to some variable,

```
string = File.open('old_file', 'r'){ |file| file.read }
```

but I can't wrap my head around what I am supposed to do next.

Maybe I could use regex to identify each time new **'create_table'** title and then somehow create new file, write content to there and close the file 'till next **'create_table'** occurrence.

How would you do this?

Comment: so there is a line break ... check if u can split it by identifing a \n or else unvisible characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a ruby solution:

```
index = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
IO.foreach("old_file.rb") do |line|                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  index += 1 if line =~ /^create_table/                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  File.open("file#{index}", 'a') do |f|                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    f.write(line)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
end
```